# Print every max value using three tables (mysql)

Tags: mysql, max

I need to find the author who has written the most volumes in my database, I have three tables "VOLUMES", "AUTHOR", "WRITTEN BY". Table VOLUMES has columns like title, volume_id(primary key), year, edition_year, etc. Table AUTHOR has columns for generic infos like name, surname, id,etc and table WRITTEN BY is used to connect AUTHOR and VOLUMES, it contains the columns volume_id and author_id.
My data can contain many copies of the same volumes so I guess I need to group every copy of the same volume.

The query I have written is:

```
SELECT A.NAME, A.SURNAME, COUNT(V.ID) no_of_volumes
FROM VOLUMES AS V, AUTHOR AS A JOIN WRITTEN_BY W
WHERE (V.ID = W.VOLUME_ID AND A.ID = W.A_ID)
GROUP BY A.NAME, A.SURNAME
ORDER BY no_of_volumes DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Now, this should print just one author, but I want it to print EVERY author that has written the same number of volumes... How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

If you are allowed to change the scheme slightly (use unique ID-names) than this could do the trick

```
select AUTHOR.NAME
,   count(*) VolumeCount

from AUTHOR
inner join WRITTEN_BY using(AUTHOR_ID)
inner join VOLUME using(VOLUME_ID)

group by a.AUTHOR_ID
order by VolumeCount desc

limit 1;
```

x
If not than this should do the trick:

```
select AUTHOR.NAME
,   count(*) VolumeCount

from AUTHOR
inner join WRITTEN_BY on AUTHOR_ID = AUTHOR.ID
inner join VOLUME on VOLUME_ID = VOLUME.ID

group by a.AUTHOR_ID
order by VolumeCount desc
limit 1;
```

Please reserve where for filtering only. Using it for foreign-key makes messy code.
(And if your table and field names are uppercase it makes sense to use lowercase keywords)

Comment: Thanks for the tips, I needed them! By using this query it still prints just one author and I know there are at least 10 authors who has written all the same number of max volumes

Answer (score 0):

You must aggregate twice inside `written_by`: once to get the max number of volumes written and then to get the author ids who wrote the max number of volumes.
Then join to `authors` to get the authors details:

```
SELECT a.*, t.no_of_volumes
FROM author a INNER JOIN (
  SELECT author_id, COUNT(*) no_of_volumes
  FROM written_by
  GROUP BY author_id
  HAVING COUNT(*) = (
    SELECT COUNT(*) no_of_volumes
    FROM written_by
    GROUP BY author_id
    ORDER BY no_of_volumes DESC LIMIT 1
  )
) t ON t.author_id = a.id
```

The table `volumes` is not needed.

For MySql 8.0+ the code can be simplified with the use of the window function `RANK()`:

```
SELECT a.*, t.no_of_volumes
FROM author a INNER JOIN (
  SELECT r.*
  FROM (
    SELECT author_id, COUNT(*) no_of_volumes, 
           RANK() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) rnk
    FROM written_by
    GROUP BY author_id
  ) r
  WHERE r.rnk = 1
) t ON t.author_id = a.id
```